# EventLog not working in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, event-log

I am working on Blackberry simulator with no real device. I have opened the EventLog by tools -> Show Event Log. But it is coming blank with no log details.

for sd card I gave path of my simulator.dmp path. I have also tried pressing alt key and then write LGLG. But nothing is happening, I just get options of youtube search, local google search and search blackberry.

My question is where do I check log results? If the event log needs a real device, is there any other way of checking it on a simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventLogger works on simulator and on actual devices. If menu in simulator does not show you log contents, [launch event log viewer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html#startEventLogViewer%28%29) **in your application**.

Just add an additional menu item to your application and launch event log viewer upon clicking on this menu item.

Additional information: on keyboard device simulator to show event log hit `Ctrl` on your computer keyboard, keep it pressed and hit **LGLG**
On actual keyboard device hit `Alt` button, keep it pressed and hit **LGLG**

[Here is the instruction to show log](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Access-device-event-log-on-Storm-4-7-emulator/m-p/133833#M15234) for touchscreen devices.